# Next pagination button not being deactivated when reaching the limit of the query using Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have an issue in which I am trying to stop the pagination when I reach the limit/maximum of the query. Since my data structure knowledge is pretty low I would ask you what would be the best solution to solve this issue?

app.py:

```
@app.route('/electronics/')
@app.route('/electronics/<page>/<limit>')
def electronics(page=1, limit=6):
    page=int(page)
    limit=int(limit)
    start_index = page * limit - limit
    end_index = start_index + 6
    all_products = mongo.db.products.find({'category_name':"Electronics"}).sort("$natural", pymongo.DESCENDING)
    page_number =math.ceil(all_products.count()/6)
    maximum = math.floor( (mongo.db.products.count_documents({})) / limit - 1)
    electronics =  all_products[start_index:end_index]
    return render_template(
        'electronics.html',
        electronics= electronics,
        page=page,
        pages=range(1, int(page_number)+1),
        maximum=maximum,
        limit=limit
    )
```

electronics.html

```
 <ul class="pagination pg-amber justify-content-center">
        <!--Previous button-->
        <li {% if page==1 %} class="page-item disabled" {% endif %}>
          <a class="page-link" {% if page>1 %}href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=page, limit=limit) }}"{% endif %}>
                            Previous
                        </a>
        </li>

        <!--Middle of the pagination-->

        {% for p in pages %}
        <li class="page-item{% if  p == page  %} active{% endif %}">
          <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=p, limit=limit) }}">{{ p }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}



       <--HERE IS THE ISSUE -->

        <!--Next button-->
        <li {% if page==maximum %} class="page-item disabled" {% endif %}>
          <a class="page-link" {% if page!=maximum %}href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=page, limit=limit) }}" {% endif %}>
                            Next
                        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is in the maximum variable, but I could not find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer for this question after long time working on it. 
So, since `maximum` variable got all products instead of the `electronic` category it did not worked into this function, retrieving all products of the DB. Therefore, I tried a way in which I could get all products within the `electronic` category which is `page_number`. Nonetheless, I added it into the page conditional instead of `maximum` as shown above and it worked.

app.py

```
@app.route('/electronics/')
@app.route('/electronics/<page>/<limit>')
def electronics(page=1, limit=6):
    page=int(page)
    limit=int(limit)
    start_index = page * limit - limit
    end_index = start_index + 6

    # used for page_number
    all_products = mongo.db.products.find({'category_name':"Electronics"}).sort("$natural", pymongo.DESCENDING)

    # used for the loop in template
    page_number =math.ceil(all_products.count()/6)

    electronics =  all_products[start_index:end_index]
    return render_template(
        'electronics.html',
        electronics= electronics,
        page=page,

        #added page_number instead of maximum
        page_number=page_number,

        pages=range(1, int(page_number)+1),
        limit=limit
```

electronics.html

```
  <li {% if page == page_number %} class="page-item disabled" {% endif %}>
          <a class="page-link" {% if page!=maximum %}href="{{ url_for('electronics', page=page, limit=limit) }}" {% endif %}>
                            Next
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `maximum` needs to be `ceil`-ed. You just have `math(`

Comment: I forgot to add .floor() method when making the question. Actually, the code wasnt working even with this method. sorry.